# Optimal way to SELECT all rows in a table that are not referenced by a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mysql-8.0

In MySQL I have a table "resources" that represents a list of resources.

eg:

```
CREATE TABLE resources (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ...etc...
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

There are about a dozen other tables in the database that have a foreign key referencing resources.

eg:

```
CREATE TABLE something (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    resourceId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ...etc...
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(resourceId) REFERENCES resources(id)
) 

CREATE TABLE somethingElse (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    resourceId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ...etc...
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(resourceId) REFERENCES resources(id)
)
```

etc...

For housekeeping, I need to periodically delete all of the rows in resources that DO NOT have a reference in any other table.

At the same time I also need to clean some things that are outside of the database that these "orphaned" resources refer to.  (eg deletion of a corresponding file.)

To do this, I start with the following select statement, to select all rows in resources that are not referenced anywhere by a foreign key:

```
select          r.id, r.name

from            resources as r 
left join       something as a on a.resourceId = r.id 
left join       somethingElse as b on b.resourceId = r.id 
left join       someOtherStuff as c on c.resourceId = r.id
left join       oneMoreExample as d on d.reosurceId = r.id 

...etc...

where           a.resourceId is null and 
                b.resourceId is null and 
                c.resourceId is null and
                d.resourceId is null 

...etc...

limit 100;
```

And then I deal with the results accordingly.

This works, and currently this query only takes about 3 seconds to run, which tbh isn't bad.  But I am worried that so many left joins have the potential to turn into a bit of bottlenck over time.

I am wondering:  Are there any other ways this query could / should be written, that might be more optimal / performant ?

Answer (score 0):

Would using a "Cascading Delete" option on the `FOREIGN KEY` avoid the need for your maintenance script?

As for "bottleneck", let's analyze the query.

If there are more than 100 to be deleted, 100 will be located, probably without scanning the entire table.  If you 'repeat' until less than 100 come back, that last pass will scan the entire `resources` table, plus probe each of the other tables once per row.  As `resources` grows, the scan takes longer.

Do not use `cron` or `EVENTs` to do the task.  You could end up with one pass not completed before it is time for the next.  Instead, have a continually running job and include a suitable `sleep` builtin so that it is not hogging the system.

It seems that, as `resources` gets larger, the query will become slower.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks for a way to walk through that table via its `PRIMARY KEY` as a way to efficiently "chunk" the results.

If you won't ever get 'many' orphaned rows, why bother?

If orphaning is frequent, consider checking when some action happens on a resource.

A "reference count" is a standard technique.  (But it may not apply in your case.)

Be sure that all the secondary tables have `referenceId` as the first column in some `INDEX`.

I suspect changing `LEFT JOIN` into `EXISTS` would be Optimized the same.